# Redirect print() output into a String instead of stdout

Tags: kotlin, inputstream, stdout

I'm trying to redirect the stdout of an object's print() function into a String variable.

In order to do this I am using the following Java imports (within Kotlin):

```
import java.io.PipedOutputStream
import java.io.PipedInputStream
import java.io.PrintStream
```

And the following function:

```
fun index(): String {

        val df_out = DataFrame.fromJson("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        val pipeOut = PipedOutputStream()
        val pipeIn = PipedInputStream(pipeOut)
        System.setOut(PrintStream(pipeOut));
        df_out.print(maxRows = 10)
        val dfAsStr = pipeIn.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        return dfAsStr
    }
```

The idea is to capture the output of the `print()` method into a `PipedInputStream` in order to be able to return it as a (processed) String.

This function code doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one. If I got your question correctly.

```
fun index(): String {
    val df_out = DataFrame.fromJson("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    val outStream = ByteArrayOutputStream().apply { System.setOut(PrintStream(df_out)) }
    df_out.print(maxRows = 10)
    return outStream.toString()
}
```